# Law of the sum of two random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have two independent standard normal random variables, $a_1$ and $a_2$. If I want to find the
Law of $(a_1 + a_2)$. Then does it mean that I just need to find the pdf of $(a_1 + a_2)$, with $a_1$ and $a_2$ follow standard normal distribution?

Comment: Short answer yes.  There are two ways to do it.  Convolution or characteristic function product.

Comment: Thank you, and another question is that are there any difference between the Laws of a r.v and the pdf function of that r.v or these are just equivalent?

Comment: Question unclear.  What do you mean by "Laws of a r.v" other than its distribution?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Why do you say only two?

Comment: I didn't say "only" two.  The two I mentioned are the simplest that I have worked with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdf of a distribution that has a pdf is one way of characterizing the distribution. The cdf is another (and works even when there is not a pdf). And there are others.

In some contexts, the answer to "Find the law" or "Find the distribution" could consist only of saying "It is normally distributed with expected value $0$ and variance $2$." or "Its distribution is $\operatorname N(0,2).$"

One can say that the density with respect to the measure $dx$ is $\displaystyle \frac1{\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\cdot2)}.$

Or one can say that the distribution is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\cdot 2)} \, dx.
$$

Notice that in one case above I said "the density is" and in the other I said "the distribution is", and I am careful about which is which.

One can say that the distribution is the function
$$
A \mapsto \int_A \frac 1 {\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\cdot 2)} \, dx \text{ for } A\subseteq \mathbb R, 
$$
i.e. the distribution is a function whose input is a subset of $\mathbb R$ and whose output is the probability assigned to that subset.

(If one knows measure theory, one adds that $A$ must be a measurable subset.)

Comment: What if I am just asked to find the law, L($a_1$+$a_2$), is it equivalent to the distribution of $a_1$+$a_2$? Does N(0,2) means the sum of N(0,1) and N(0,1) is N(0,2)?

Comment: @brian24 : In many contexts, I would answer that by saying $a_1+a_2\sim\operatorname N(0,2).$ And possibly cite a theorem of which that is a special case. But if the problem is to prove that theorem, then I might compute a convolution.

Comment: Okay, so there are no differences between "the law of a r.v" and "the distribution of a r.v"?

Comment: @brian24 : "Law" and "distribution" in this context are synonyms.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!